# Page Flickering Asp.Net Using Master Page Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have masterpage and i am using update panels for all my partial page renderings and panels. When i run this on my local machine the postbacks dont casue flickering but when i run from the host server the whole page flikers on postback. any ideas?

Comment: the requests are taking too long.

Comment: so is there a way to fix? My guess is it is reloading the masterpage on every postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link and it prevents masterpage flickering. the re-load time will remain the same but is much easier on the user's eyes.

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
```

Source : [Prevent Master_Page Flickering](http://srinisreeramoju.blogspot.com/2010/03/net-preventing-master-page-flickering.html)

Comment: Well come to find out the above link only worked in IE and not FireFox

Comment: Not perfect, but it is better for IE, even newer version (Edge).